# I_CHILDRENCALLBACK 64bit failing

Tags: c++, windows, tree, mfc

The following works in 32bit mode, but not in 64bit, for TVN_ITEMEXPANDING mouse click & keyboard events.

**Object.h**

```
afx_msg void OnTvnItemexpandingTreectrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
```

**Object.cpp**

```
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Object, CDialogEx)
        ON_NOTIFY(TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, IDC_TREECTRL, OnTvnItemexpandingTreectrl)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void Object::LoadTree()
{
    m_TreeCtrl1.DeleteAllItems();

    HTREEITEM hParentItem = TVI_ROOT;

    std::list<OBJ>::iterator itObj = m_Obj.begin()->m_Obj.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Obj.begin()->m_Obj.size(); i++, ++itObj)
    {
        TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
        TVITEM tvItem = { 0 };

        tvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM | TVIF_CHILDREN  | TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_STATE;
        tvItem.cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK;

        tvItem.pszText = itObj->m_TreeDesc.GetBuffer();
        tvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_ITEMLEN;
        tvItem.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&*itObj);
        tvis.item = tvItem;
        tvis.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
        tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
        hParentItem = m_TreeCtrl1.InsertItem(&tvis);
        RecurseBuildTree(itObj->m_Obj, m_TreeCtrl1, hParentItem, TVI_LAST);
    }

    hParentItem = m_TreeCtrl1.GetFirstVisibleItem();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Obj.begin()->m_Obj.size(); i++)
    {
        HTREEITEM hNext = hParentItem;
        OBJ *pObjNext = reinterpret_cast<OBJ*>(m_TreeCtrl1.GetItemData(hNext));
        m_TreeCtrl1.SetCheck(hNext, pObjNext->m_bItemDisplayed);
        RecurseTreeSetCheck(m_TreeCtrl1, hParentItem);
        hParentItem = m_TreeCtrl1.GetNextItem(hNext, TVGN_NEXT);
    }
}


    void Object::OnTvnItemexpandingTreectrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMTREEVIEW pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);
        *pResult = 0;
    }


    void ExpandTreeItem(CTreeCtrl &tree, HTREEITEM hItem, UINT nCode)
    {
        HTREEITEM hChild;
        if (tree.ItemHasChildren(hItem))
        {
            tree.Expand(hItem, nCode);
            hChild = tree.GetChildItem(hItem);

            while (hChild)
            {
                ExpandTreeItem(tree, hChild, nCode);
                hChild = tree.GetNextItem(hChild, TVGN_NEXT);
            }
        }
    }


void Object::ToggleItemState(HTREEITEM hti, CTreeCtrl &treectrl, const HTREEITEM hParentNode)
{
    if (hti == hParentNode)
    {
        const int iImage = treectrl.GetItemState(hParentNode, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) >> 12;
        OBJ *pObj = reinterpret_cast<OBJ*>(treectrl.GetItemData(hti));
        pObj->m_bItemDisplayed = (iImage == 1 ? 2 : 1);
    }
    else
    {
        const int iImage = treectrl.GetItemState(hParentNode, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) >> 12;
        treectrl.SetItemState(hti, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(iImage == 1 ? 2 : 1), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
        OBJ *pObj = reinterpret_cast<OBJ*>(treectrl.GetItemData(hti));
        pObj->m_bItemDisplayed = (iImage == 1 ? 2 : 1);
    }

    if (treectrl.ItemHasChildren(hti)) //failing in release mode for root level node.
    {
        HTREEITEM htiChild = treectrl.GetChildItem(hti);

        if (htiChild)
            ToggleItemState(htiChild, treectrl, hParentNode);
        else
            return;
        HTREEITEM htiSibling = treectrl.GetNextSiblingItem(htiChild);
        while (htiSibling)
        {
            ToggleItemState(htiSibling, treectrl, hParentNode);
            htiSibling = treectrl.GetNextSiblingItem(htiSibling);
        }
    }
}
```

**Observations:**

Following is failing in 64bit release mode but only for root node:

```
if (treectrl.ItemHasChildren(hti))
```

I have button that can manually call ExpandTreeItem() & tree.Expand() calls OnTvnItemexpandingTreectrl(), but in 64bit mode mouse & keyboard doesn't call TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, for other events it works fine.

I suspect it may have something to do with initialization of

```
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
    TVITEM tvItem = { 0 };
```

but don't really know what I'm looking for.

Let me know if I need to post more code.

Thanks

Comment: Scanning through your code I see `m_TreeDesc.GetBuffer()` but there is no `ReleaseBuffer()`

Comment: ReleaseBuffer isn't needed, because the length doesn't change... The documentations tells us to do so, but the Implantation shows, that this is only needed if the length changes. (And this is the case since MFC 1.0) So Yes, it should be done, and No it isn't a possible reason for an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I may have found the cause:

```
    tvItem.cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK; //<<failing in 64bit mode. 
    //Upto 0xFFFFFFFE works ok but not -1?
```

Following minimal code can be used to replicate the issue:

```
//header
struct ItemData
{
    CString  Name;
    int      Value;

    CString ToString() const
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format(_T("%s = %d"), Name, Value);
        return str;
    }
};


CTreeCtrl m_tree;
std::vector<ItemData*> m_data;


//source
void CTreeSortDemoDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TREE, m_tree);
}

void CTreeSortDemoDlg::GenerateTreeContent()
{
    ItemData* data1 = new ItemData;
    data1->Value = 3;
    data1->Name.Format(_T("%c%c"), 'P', data1->Value);
    m_data.push_back(data1);
    m_data.push_back(data1);

    ItemData* data2 = new ItemData;
    data2->Value = 3;
    data2->Name.Format(_T("%c%c"), 'P', data2->Value);
    m_data.push_back(data2);
    m_data.push_back(data2);

    HTREEITEM hParentItem = TVI_ROOT;

    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
    TVITEM tvItem = { 0 };

    tvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM | TVIF_CHILDREN | TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_STATE;
    tvItem.cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK; //<<failing in 64bit mode. 1 works ok?

    tvItem.pszText = L"Parent";
    tvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
    tvItem.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&m_data);
    tvis.item = tvItem;
    tvis.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
    tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
    hParentItem = m_tree.InsertItem(&tvis);

    //////
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis2;
    TVITEM tvItem2 = { 0 };
    std::vector<ItemData*>::iterator itData = m_data.begin();

    tvItem2.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM | TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_STATE;
    tvItem2.cChildren = 0;
    tvItem2.pszText = L"child";
    tvItem2.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
    tvItem2.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&itData);
    tvis2.item = tvItem2;

    tvis2.hParent = hParentItem;
    tvis2.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
    HTREEITEM hItemThis = m_tree.InsertItem(&tvis2);
}
```

EDIT:

If I_CHILDRENCALLBACK is to be used in tree generation then TVN_GETDISPINFO must also be used ie

```
   ON_NOTIFY(TVN_GETDISPINFO, IDC_TREE, OnGetdispinfoTreectrl)


void CTreeSortDemoDlg::OnGetdispinfoTreectrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTVDISPINFO pTVDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTVDISPINFO>(pNMHDR);
    TVITEM* pItem = &(pTVDispInfo)->item;

    ItemData *pData = reinterpret_cast<ItemData*>(pItem->lParam);

    if (pItem->mask & TVIF_CHILDREN)
    {
        if (pData != NULL)
        {
            pItem->cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK;
        }
    }
}
```

Odd still how behaviour exhibits itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution simply the design of the message?

Here a quote form the documentation [TVM_EXPAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb773568(v=vs.85).aspx)

> When an item is first expanded by a TVM_EXPAND message, the action generates TVN_ITEMEXPANDING and TVN_ITEMEXPANDED notification codes and the item's TVIS_EXPANDEDONCE state flag is set. As long as this state flag remains set, subsequent TVM_EXPAND messages do not generate TVN_ITEMEXPANDING or TVN_ITEMEXPANDED notifications. To reset the TVIS_EXPANDEDONCE state flag, you must send a TVM_EXPAND message with the TVE_COLLAPSE and TVE_COLLAPSERESET flags set. Attempting to explicitly set TVIS_EXPANDEDONCE will result in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: If this was the case wouldn't both 32 & 64 bit exhibit the same issue?